# Building executable for mutliple test files

Tags: c++, c, linux, executable, googlemock

I have 2 .cpp files with my test cases. **Test1.cpp** contains tests for file1.c and **Test2.cpp** contains test for file2.c.

Both the files required some common functions to be mocked and so I have a put all the mocked methods in a header file, **test_header.h** and have included this header file to Test1.cpp and Test2.cpp.

In test_header.h, I have used **#ifndef** and **#define** in order to avoid redefinition of the mocked methods. But, while building the executable I am getting **redefinition error** for all the mocked methods.

Example code:-

**Test1.cpp**

```
#include "test_header.h"

class MocktestFile1: public ::testing::Test
{
    void SetUp() {}
};

TEST_F(MocktestFile1, Func1_Test)
{
    int arg1=0, arg2=0;
    EXPECT_GLOBAL_CALL(mockfunc1, mockfunc1(_,_)).Times(1);      
    int a= Func1( arg1, arg2);
    ASSERT_EQ(a, 2);
}
```

**Test2.cpp**

```
#include "test_header.h"

class MocktestFile2 : public ::testing::Test
{
    void SetUp() {}
};

TEST_F(MocktestFile2, Func2_Test)
{
    int arg1=1, arg2=1;
    EXPECT_GLOBAL_CALL(mockfunc1, mockfunc1(_,_)).Times(1);
    int a= Func2( arg1, arg2);
    ASSERT_EQ(a, 10);
}
```

**test_header.h**

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gmock-global/gmock-global.h"


#ifndef MOCK
#define MOCK

MOCK_GLOBAL_FUNC2(mockfunc1, int(int, int));

#endif
```

A **test_runner.cpp** contains the main() function.

Could someone help me with the **redefinition error**? Shouldn't the **#ifndef** prevent the redefinition?

Thank you.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. You should provide a minimal code example.

Comment: There's a `#` missing before `ifndef MOCK` in your posted code!

Comment: What *is* the "issue"? Please elaborate on what problems you have inside the question itself. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: Hi, I the issue I was talking about is the redefinition error. Also, thank you. I will definitely give those a read. I apologize for not being clear with my question. This is my first time posting a question.

Comment: Hi @Adrian, thank you for pointing it out. I must have missed it while adding the code here.

Answer (score 1):

The `#ifndef` / `#define` combination just makes sure that the enclosed block is only seen **once** per compilation unit, but you have **two** compilation units. Both of them include the enclosed block.

Put the method **definition** in its own module, for example `mock.cpp`. Keep only its **declaration** in the header file.

Comment: I am compiling both the files together to create one executable. I thought while building the executable, if the mocked methods are defined once then it won't be defined the second time.